# How to join two different tables horizontally (without cross join)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a SQL project and i'm not good enough. I loaded data to a denormalized table. Then I inserted data to father and mother table from this denormalized table. Now I need to insert data to family table which has two foreign keys (mother_mother_id and father_father_id). So here is my thing, I want to take some columns from denormalized data like family_size, family_type and also for foreign keys, I need to take father_id from father table and mother_id from mother table.

According to other stackoverflow questions everyone suggested full outer join. But my tables have no common column to use an "on" situtation. For this issue I tried to join this data without any "on" condition. Then SQL apply cross join and I don't want this.

For example I've got these tables

Table A

| carModel | year |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1999 |
| y | 2005 |

Table B

| computer | price |
| --- | --- |
| t | 1000 |
| z | 2000 |

Table C

| food | cals |
| --- | --- |
| b | 500 |
| n | 600 |

Here is the result I want

Table D

| carModel | year | computer | price | food | cals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1999 | t | 1000 | b | 500 |
| y | 2005 | z | 2000 | n | 600 |

I'm using MySQL 8.0

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (although I cannot imagine why this is something you would want)

Comment: You said (about 3 times) "Then SQL apply cross join and I don't want this." but you failed explaining WHY you do not want to do that.  Also "But I got an error while uploading the data." ?? What can we (a reader on SO) do with this statement?

Comment: CROSS JOIN cannot help due to joining multiplying. So do not be afraid - you do not need to use CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a fiddle to solve this question:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3MGCAaL1YU4ZdkRGfSwPPK/0

First the tables are created:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (carModel varchar(20),year int);
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES('x',1999),('y',2005);

CREATE TABLE TableB (computer varchar(20),price int);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES('t',1000),('z',2000);

CREATE TABLE TableC (food varchar(20),cals int);
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES('b',500),('y',600);
```

And then queried:

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() R,
     carModel,year
  FROM TableA),
     B AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() R,
     computer,price
  FROM TableB),
     C AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() R,
     food,cals
  FROM TableC)
SELECT A.carModel, A.year, B.computer, B.price, C.food,C.cals
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.R=A.R
INNER JOIN C ON C.R=A.R;
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, thanks. In addition, I will try to ask my questions more clearly in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of things. what finally worked for me was, the following query (with 3 queries as you).

```
WITH
A AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER() iter, High_Number
    FROM
    (
        SELECT zipcode as "High_Number"
        FROM census
        ORDER BY total_population desc
        LIMIT 5
    )
),
B AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER() iter, High_Ratio
    FROM
    (
        SELECT zipcode as High_Ratio
        FROM census
        ORDER BY number_latinos/total_population desc
        LIMIT 5
    )
),
C AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER() iter, Worst_Zipcode
    FROM
    (
        SELECT zipcode as Worst_zipcode
        FROM census
        WHERE number_latinos > 5
        ORDER BY number_latinos/total_population asc
        LIMIT 5
    )
)

SELECT A.High_Number, B.High_Ratio, C.Worst_Zipcode
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON  A.iter = B.iter
INNER JOIN C ON  A.iter = C.iter
```